# How to check if dictionary values are 'list' type?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

How to check exactly if the type of value in the dictioanary are list type or not

i have list which need to check against the key's in  the dictionary 'test_dict' if its exist and to know if any of values are 'list' type

```
col_list = ['pat_cd','dsply_nm', 'opt_cd','dsply_val']

test_dict={'pat_cd':'123','opt_cd':['232','245'],'test':['123','1232']}

result=type(any(test_dict[i]) for i in col_list if i in test_dict) is list
print(result)
##
Output
False
```

The out put return 'False'.. Ideally it should return 'True' since value of 'opt_cd' is list type

Can anyone help to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: but key `test` is not in the `col_list`, so should it be checked..?

Comment: `any(isinstance(test_dict[i], list) for i in col_list if i in test_dict)`?

Comment: @alex, i have updated the question. only those against the col_list need to check if  it its list type

Comment: [Best way to check if a variable is a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106905/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-list)   and [What are the differences between type and instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance) cover the how - your problem is incorrect usage of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
any(isinstance(test_dict.get(k, None), list) for k in col_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is how you've used the keywords `type` and `any`. for example `any` works on a list of booleans. Their usage in Python is not the same as their use in English. `any(test_dict[i])` will always return `True` so your code creates an iterator of `True` and an iterator is *not* a list. So it will always return false.

Also it is recommended to use `isinstance(something,class_name)` of instead of `type(something) is class_name`.

Although @alex's answer works. Since you're new to python I would recommend you use for loops instead. It might even help the performance if the size of your dictionary or list is large.

```
result = False
for k in col_list:
    if isinstance(test_dict.get(k, None), list):
        result=True
        break
```

Which is almost equivalent to the one liner but more readable for a beginner.:

```
result = any(isinstance(test_dict.get(k, None), list) for k in col_list)
```